# Laravel Unit Test (The response is not a view)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I am doing unit testing to my web application. My experience with Laravel and PHP Unit Testing too young. Now, I am just fiddling around with the Laravel Unit test. Now, I am testing if a view returned to the route contains specific text. Very simple. This is what I have done.

I created a view called, unit_test.blade.php with the following content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    This is unit test
</body>
</html>
```

This is the route to display that view

```
Route::get('unit/test', function(){
   return view('unit_test');
});
```

This is my test class and function

```
class ApiV2EventController extends TestCase
{


    public function testUnitTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('unit/test');

        $response->assertViewHas('unit');
    }
}
```

My test function is simple. It is just checking if the view contains the text, "unit". But when I run the test in the command line, it is giving

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\ApiV2EventController::testUnitTest
The response is not a view.
```

I am returning the view in the route. What is wrong with my code? How can I test it?

Comment: that's not a unit test, that looks like an acceptance test

Comment: But what is wrong with my code? I am doing it right though. But not giving me the expected result

Comment: Shouldn't you `return View::make('unit_test');` ?

Comment: It is the old way of laravel

Comment: Even if I used, View::make() it is till giving me the same error

Comment: If I run your code, I get a different error: `Failed asserting that an array has the key 'unit'.` Where is `unit_test.blade.php` located?

Comment: It is under resources/views folder

Comment: If I set an invalid view (a file that doesn't exists) I get the same error `The response is not a view.`

You can get the exact rendered HTML by doing `echo $response->content();` in your test case and check the output. This would show if there are any other errors.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice. I used this way, $this->assertContains('unit', $response->content())  and it works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `$response->content()` in the test case to check the actual rendered HTML.

And an extra: you can use `$response->assertSeeText($string)` to check that any string exists in the HTML. That method is pretty much what you did (`$this->assertContains('unit', $response->content())`) with an extra call to `strip_tags()`.

And as another extra, `$response->assertViewHas()` is used when you pass data to your view, e.g.

```
Route::get('unit/test', function() {
    return view('unit_test', [
        'some_var' => 'some value',
    ]);
});
```

And in the test case:

```
$response = $this->get('unit/test');
$response->assertViewHas('some_var');
```

Answer (score 4):

In your test try to disable Exception Handling to see what's going on.

```
$this->withoutExceptionHandling();
```

Comment: Please also explain _why_ this fix would work, or what root problem it fixes or prevents.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be a redirection response.

For example you're not authenticated and requested a protected route, you'll receive a redirection response to login with status 302.